# Why do I have to change Media Sets to create a Full Backup to a new file and what does that mean?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to create an ad-hoc Full Backup as a snapshot of the database in time and when I added a new file to backup to I get the following error:

[image: Error]

I see I can surpass this error by going to Media Options and changing the Overwrite Media to "Back up to a new media set, and erase all existing backup sets". What does this mean?...will I lose my existing backups if I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a long topic and for the most part it relates to technology that is irrelevant in this day and age (more specifically: tape storage). However here is a quick summary:

> **media set**
>
> An ordered collection of backup media, tapes or disk files, to which one or more backup operations have written using a fixed type and number of backup devices.
>
> **media family**
>
> Backups created on a single nonmirrored device or a set of mirrored devices in a media set
>
> **backup set**
>
> The backup content that is added to a media set by a successful backup operation.

In short, if you create a new media set on a device, then yes, you will lose all of your previous backups:

> **Creating a new media set**
>
> To create a new media set, you must format the backup media (one or more tapes or disk files). The formatting process changes the backup media as follows:
>
> 1. Deletes the old header (if any), effectively deleting the previous contents of the backup media.
> 2. Formatting a tape device deletes all previous contents of the currently mounted tape. Formatting a disk affects only the file that you specify for the backup operation
> 3. Writes a new media header on the backup media (tape or disk file) on each of the backup devices.

For more information, checkout the [Media sets, media families & backup sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/media-sets-media-families-and-backup-sets-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation over at Microsoft Docs.

Comment: Is there a way to just take a Full Backup snapshot now without loosing previous backups and restoring it to another server?

Comment: I would recommend performing a [Copy-Only Backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/copy-only-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to a completely new file. Doing this will preserve your existing media set and it will not break your log chain.

Comment: Full backups never break the log chain.  Copy-Only backups don't reset the differential base.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft sorry, there was a lot of assumption in my comment above that I should have explained. I assumed that he was taking an ad-hoc backup to restore to another server but not taking the original offline. I also assumed that as it was outside of the regular backup schedule there was a possibility that this backup would not be retained in the same location or at all - I suggested the copy only to eliminate this risk. Fully aware though that a full backup, if retained does not break the log chain and that the copy only does not alter any differential bits.

Comment: A full backup, even if not retained, does not break the log chain.  The log records inside a full backup will be also be present in the next log backup.

Comment: I genuinely did not know that - I always thought performing a full in-between log backups broke the chain, thanks for teaching me something!

Comment: It is a common misconception, as DBAs are naturally reluctant to throw away backups.  But important because if you lose a Full backup, you can recover from a previous Full backup and all the log backups.